# With Git, is there a way to push multiple branches to the same package?

Tags: git, merge

I've only been working with Git a few months so I may not be asking the question correctly.  Here's the situation:
I work on multiple project at once.  I've been creating a branch for each project.  I'll call them 1,2, and 3.  Each of these branches need pushed to the test server.  We only have one master, and that's production code, so I've been pushing the fix branches to the test server, we use Jenkins.
The problem is for each of the users to test the fixes, I've been merging all the branches together.  The problem is fix 1 may go but fixes 2 and 3 aren't approved yet. So I have to seperate out fixes 2 and 3 then merge with master.
The only solution I've been able to come up with was to merge the branches in a 4th branch I'll call testbranch.  This seemed to work fine until I promoted branch 1 then for cleanup deleted branch 1 off the remote server and locally.  For some reason, this cause a tracking error with testbranch, and required me deleting and recreating testbranch.
This just seems like a lot of work, and I was hoping there was a simpler way.

Comment: If they are really separate projects, why not use three different repositories?

Comment: "I've been creating a branch for each project." Git is designed, and works _much_ better, for one project per repository. Git branches are _not_ for separate projects, but for different variations on the same codebase. "The problem is for each of the users to test the fixes, I've been merging all the branches together." Why would you do this? It leads directly to the problem you're describing.

Comment: @blcook223 - My company calls all changes projects.  

There are 250+ html files, not counting js and css in one repository - I have no control over creating new ones. Several html changes can occur at once while all won't go live at the same time. I would think this is common - having several changes in the same code base.  Each branch could be tested separately, but because changes need promoted to the test server to be tested, I need a way for branches to be tested together for UAT.  My current way works but has issues.  I need a way to achieve this without issues.

Comment: @blcook223 Thanks.  After reading the article you recommended, I think the GitFlow WorkFlow or Feature Branch Workflow would work.  The only thing I need to know now is how to mark your answer as answering my question.

Comment: @JohnMeyer, I'm glad it was helpful for you. I've made my comment and answer and will delete the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to agree with the comment from Chris that your company is not using Git as it's intended, so it's not surprising that there are some hiccups. I would recommend [this article](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows). Maybe you could adapt the git-flow workflow to your situation, although I have to think that your company would be better served in the long run by separating the projects into different repos.